# How to get request url in ruby Sinatra class context?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra you have the possibility to get the request full path by using the following lines:

```
get '/hello-world' do
  request.path_info   # => '/hello-world'
  request.fullpath    # => '/hello-world?foo=bar'
  request.url         # => 'http://example.com/hello-world?foo=bar'
end
```

I have several classes I use in my app. In this one particular class I like to compare the `request.path_info` to a string.

```
class foo
  def build_menu
    if request.path_info == "/hello-world"
      highlight_menu_entry
    end
  end
end
```

But the `request`-Object is not known in this class context and an error is thrown. I though this is a SUPER-GLOBAL like in PHP `$_POST` or `$_GET`, if there is some in Ruby/Sinatra.

So how can I check the `request.path` in a class context?

Comment: Where is the class instance (e.g. foo.build_menu) being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by my myself. I use a self defined global variable `$PATHNAME` which I can use in any context. Combined with the `before do`-preprocessor in my main app, I can fill an use the variable.

```
before do
  $PATHNAME=request.path_info
end

class Foo
  def build_menu
    highlight_menu_entry if $PATHNAME == '/hello-world'
  end
end
```

Comment: This is bound to fail in cases where requests are being treated in parallel, you should really consider using @rcrews 's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value to your class:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :request_path_info, :request_fullpath, :request_url
  def build_menu
    highlight_menu_entry if request_path_info == '/hello-world'
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

get '/hello-world' do
  foo.request_path_info = request.path_info
  foo.request_fullpath = request.fullpath
  foo.request_url = request.url
end

foo.build_menu
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. So I have to take the long way. I thought there might be something like a global variable, which I can use in any context.